# Pattern match SubValues with unspecified number of arguments

Tags: pattern-matching

Does there exist a single pattern that would match `SubValues` of arbitrary "length" with a given head? For example, I would like to match all of the following

```
f[x]
f[x][y]
f[x][y][z]
f[x][y][z][w]
...
```

Comment: This question has been [asked before on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958128/arbitrarily-deep-nested-pattern-matching). I can't mark it as a duplicate because that's a separate site, but otherwise it is a duplicate. You can find solutions to your question there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll close the question

Comment: Please don't close it. Others with this question who come to this site, will see it and a reference to the other one. Thanks.